# Easy way to write cp -a in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

So since PowerShell seems to have alises to bash commands they still don't follow them 100%...

What is the easiest way to write bash's `cp -a` in PowerShell format?

Answer (score 1):

The `-r` flag which stands for recursive.

```
cp -r
```